# ReactCSSTransitionGroup: Почему не работает transitionAppear?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, анимация, jsx, reactcsstransitiongroup

Пытаюсь сделать плавное появление/исчезновение уведомления, но не работает `transitionAppear`. Делаю добавление элемента(всплытие уведомления) на событие `onBlur`(после того, когда делаю клик за пределами инпута). Анимация во время `leave` работает плавно, а во время `appear` просто резко появляется без `transition`. В Реакте совсем недавно, не ругайтесь сильно:D

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/l26j10613q

**P.S.**
Если я добавлю `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` в `alert.js` — `appear` работает, но `leave` нет.

**`alert.js:`**

```
export default class Alert extends Component {
  render() {
    const { icon, text } = this.props;
    let classNames = "cards-wrapper-alert";
    return (
     <div className={classNames}>
       <Card zIndex="2">
         <Icon icon={icon} eClass="alert-message-icon"/>
         <Label text={text} fw="fw-medium" fs="fs-14" fc="c-dark"/>
       </Card>
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**`alert.css:`**

```
.alert-appear {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.alert-appear.alert-appear-active {
  max-height: 80px;
  transition: max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.alert-leave {
  max-height: 80px;
}

.alert-leave.alert-leave-active {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

**`input.js:`**

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup
  component={this.prepareComponentForAnimation}
  transitionName="alert"
  transitionEnter={false}
  transitionAppear={true}
  transitionAppearTimeout={400}
  transitionLeaveTimeout={400}>
  {this.state.alert ?
    React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
      icon: this.state.icon,
      text: this.state.text
    })
  : null}
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

**Example:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решён. Нужно было использовать `transitionEnter` вместо `transitionAppear`.

> `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` предоставляет необязательный prop `transitionAppear`,
>  для добавления дополнительной фазы перехода на начальном монтировании компонента.

[Вопрос решён здесь [En StackOverflow]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53324007/9464680)

[CodeSandbox - answer](https://codesandbox.io/s/mz1knpr288)